# How to correctly Pass Dictionary<Tupel<string,string>,Object> as paramater to a method

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am attempting to invoke a UserControl public method that requires a reference to a Dictionary object with the following definition:

```
var dict = new Dictionary <Tuple<string, string>, Mappings.Level0>()
```

My call statement: uc.MyMthod(dict) can not compile due to the following error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<ListBoxConnector.ucMappings.Tuple<string,string>,Mappings.Level0>`
>   to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Tuple<string,string>,Mappings.Level0>`

Comment: Well, the error is fairly self-explanatory. You are passing the wrong Tuple to the method (you're passing a `ListBoxConnector.ucMappings.Tuple` instead of a `System.Tuple`). Can you show the code you're using to call the method with?

Comment: the call statement: ucColumns1.Level0(ucMappings1.dict)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `ListBoxConnector.ucMappings` Tuple instead:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<ListBoxConnector.ucMappings.Tuple<string, string>, 
    Mappings.Level0>();
```

Comment: Thanks Rufus, your initial observation was correct.